# Making buttons by cycle with lambda and getattr

Tags: python, python-3.x, lambda, pyqt5, getattr

I'm trying to use `getattr` inside lambda and I`m getting error: is it possible to do like this or not?

This code works well:

```
#it connects commands to buttons
for i in range(10):
    getattr(ui, 'btn%s' % i).clicked.connect(lambda i, j=i:  self.pressed_number(str(j)))
```

This code does not work:

```
for i in ['C', 'CA', 'Backspace', 'Decimal', 'PlusMinus', 'Enter']:
    getattr(ui, 'btn%s' % i).clicked.connect(lambda i, self, j=i: getattr(self, 'pressed_%s()' % j.lower()))
```

Comment: Post your error message

Comment: In the first example `i` is a number 0-9. In the second example `i` is a string (`'C'`, `'CA'`, etc.) so `'btn%s' % i` evaluates to a different string

Comment: When I press the button for e.g. "C" PyCharm concole says: Process finished with exit code 255

Comment: Your lambda expression in the second example expects 2 or 3 arguments, but `QPushButton.clicked` only emits one. You need to specify a default value for the second parameter of the lambda expression as well to make this work.

Comment: The `getattr` syntax is wrong as well. You need: `connect(lambda x, self=self, j=i: getattr(self, 'pressed_%s' % j.lower())())`. That is because `getattr` returns a *callable object*, which you then need to explcitly call.

Comment: PS: and please learn how to configure PyCharm so that it shows you the full Python traceback. An exit code is usually no help at all.

Answer (score 0):

The right code is:

```
for i in ['C', 'CA', 'Backspace', 'Decimal', 'PlusMinus', 'Enter']:
    getattr(ui, 'btn%s' % i).clicked.connect(lambda i, j=i: getattr(self, 'pressed_%s' % j.lower())())
```